Problem deploying node rest api in render
I am trying to deploy my rest api created in node with typescript in render. However, at the time of deployment I get the following log:
==> Exited with status 127
==> Common ways to troubleshoot your deploy: https://docs.render.com/troubleshooting-deploys
==> Using Node version 20.15.1 (default)
==> Docs on specifying a Node version: https://render.com/docs/node-version
==> Using Bun version 1.1.0 (default)
==> Docs on specifying a bun version: https://render.com/docs/bun-version
==> Running 'npm run dev'
> drivesafe-backend@1.0.0 dev
> nodemon ./src/app.ts
sh: 1: nodemon: not found

When deploying I put in root directory: src. In build command: npm install. And in start command:
npm run dev
This is the package.json of my project
{
  "name": "drivesafe-backend",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "nodemon ./src/app.ts"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "description": "",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/bcryptjs": "^2.4.6",
    "@types/cors": "^2.8.17",
    "@types/dotenv": "^6.1.1",
    "@types/express": "^4.17.21",
    "@types/jsonwebtoken": "^9.0.7",
    "@types/multer": "^1.4.12",
    "@types/mysql2": "github:types/mysql2",
    "@types/sequelize": "^4.28.20"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "bcryptjs": "^2.4.3",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "dotenv": "^16.4.5",
    "express": "^4.21.0",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^9.0.2",
    "multer": "^1.4.5-lts.1",
    "mysql2": "^3.11.3",
    "sequelize": "^6.37.3"
  }
}

I have tried putting this in build command:
npm install npm install typescript -g npm install i ts-node -g npm install i nodemon -g tsc —init npm init -y npm i express cors dotenv multer mysql2 npm i @types/express @types/cors @types/dotenv @types/multer -D npm i --save-dev types/mysql2# npm i bcryptjs npm i jsonwebtoken
However, when I do this I get another problem:
==> Docs on specifying a Node version: https://render.com/docs/node-version
==> Using Bun version 1.1.0 (default)
==> Docs on specifying a bun version: https://render.com/docs/bun-version
==> Running build command 'npm install npm install typescript -g npm install i ts-node -g npm install i nodemon -g tsc —init npm init -y npm i express cors dotenv multer mysql2 npm i @types/express @types/cors @types/dotenv @types/multer -D npm i --save-dev types/mysql2# npm i bcryptjs npm i jsonwebtoken'...
npm error arg Argument starts with non-ascii dash, this is probably invalid: —init
npm error code EINVALIDTAGNAME
npm error Invalid tag name "—init" of package "—init": Tags may not have any characters that encodeURIComponent encodes.
npm error A complete log of this run can be found in: /opt/render/.cache/_logs/2024-10-06T17_05_36_663Z-debug-0.log
==> Build failed 
==> Common ways to troubleshoot your deploy: https://docs.render.com/troubleshooting-deploys```


Your first problem is that nodemon is not listed as a devDependency.
Your should install it using npm install --save-dev nodemon. Then it will be available with the rest of your dependencies.
In your second try, the formatting of the command is not valid. You can't just add multiple install commands into a single line separated by whitespace. Either try listing multiple dependencies using a single install command or seperate multiple commands with &&.

The last line in your log shows the actual error:
sh: 1: nodemon: not found

Your script states
 "scripts": {
    "dev": "nodemon ./src/app.ts"
  },

But nodemon is not part of your dependencies. This happens as you have nodemon on your local machine globally installed. But this dependency is missing on your server.
You can add nodemon to your dependencies and this should work. But render is most likely restart your app on crash for you so i would recommend to add a start script "start": "node index.js" as you notice you should run the .js build not the typescript src file ;)
